# Why is the memory usage of an application is too different on different devices?

Tags: android, performance, memory

I have test my simple app on 2 diference devices (Samsung GT-S7262 and HTC One)

As the test result, the memory usage on the Samsung device is **~20 times higher**.

Why is that while the Samsung device have a smaller screen, lower RAM and lower CPU?

Comment: More details would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of reasons for this,

1] Each of those devices are running a different version of Android, and are likely running different types of software in the background. If your not experiencing any problems, and your users aren't complaining - I dont see anything to worry about.

2] Samsung has additional layer of libraries for their custom UI on Android, which will eventually lead the app to consume more memory. HTC devices have stock/native Android not sure. Your variables and objects take x memory in both devices, but your UI elements take more memory in Samsung in comparison to moto device.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer